# How to grid plot 2D categorical data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, categorical-data

I hava data that looks like:

```
Name X    Y
A    HIGH MID
B    LOW  LOW
C    MID  LOW
D    HIGH MID
```

How to plot this data in a 2-D diagram with a 3x3 grid adding a random variation to place each data point including its name with enough spacing between each other.

So it should look somewhat like that:
[image]

The following i tried, but i dont know how to plot the values not exactly on the grid, but in between, so they do nbot overlap.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### Mock Data ###
data = """A0,LOW,LOW
A,MID,MID
B,LOW,MID
C,MID,HIGH
D,LOW,MID
E,HIGH,HIGH"""

df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in data.split('\n')])
df.columns = ['name','X','Y']

### Plotting ###
fig,axs = plt.subplots()
axs.scatter(df.X,df.Y,label=df.name)
axs.set_xlabel('X')
axs.set_ylabel('Y')
for i,p in enumerate(df.name):
    axs.annotate(p, (df.X[i],df.Y[i]))
axs.grid()
axs.set_axisbelow(True)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

resulting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control directly the positions and change the labels on the axis. There are a few problems with your drawing because you are not taking into account some issue such as "what label will you have if you have more than one point at the same location?".

In any case here is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

### Mock Data ###
data = """A0,LOW,LOW
A,MID,MID
B,LOW,MID
C,MID,HIGH
D,LOW,MID
E,HIGH,HIGH"""

df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in data.split('\n')])
df.columns = ['name','X','Y']

pos = [0, 1, 2]
lbls = ["LOW", "MID", "HIGH"]
trans = {lbls[i]:pos[i] for i in range(len(pos))}

mat = np.zeros((3, 3), dtype="U10") # This is limited to 10 characters
xxs = []
yys = []
offset = 0.05

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    xc, yc = trans[df.X[i]], trans[df.Y[i]]
    if mat[xc, yc]=="":
        mat[xc, yc] = df.name[i]
    else:
        mat[xc, yc] = mat[xc, yc] + ";" + df.name[i]
    xxs.append(xc)
    yys.append(yc)
fig,axs = plt.subplots()
axs.scatter(xxs, yys)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    name = mat[xxs[i], yys[i]]
    axs.text(xxs[i]+offset, yys[i]+offset, name)
axs.set_xticks(pos)
axs.set_xticklabels(lbls)
axs.set_yticks(pos)
axs.set_yticklabels(lbls)
for i in pos:
    axs.axhline(pos[i]-0.5, color="black")
    axs.axvline(pos[i]-0.5, color="black")
axs.set_xlim(-0.5, 2.5)
axs.set_ylim(-0.5, 2.5)
plt.show()
```

This result in the following image:

[image: customized categorical scatter plot]

Comment: looks great thanks! As you already stated, there will be conflicts for names with the same X,Y values: Therefore I would like to randomly place the plotted points inside each grid field in such way that the annotated texts do not overlay each other.

Comment: @gustavz Well the solution I've provided is just to build labels specific for each cell using ";" as separator (as can be seen in the "LOW:MID" coordinate in the example). To randomly produce locations inside the cell you'll need to use something like 'np.random.uniform(pos[i]-0.5, pos[i]+0.5)' for an X and Y for each of the labels. But I recommend against this since this will not guarantee the labels won't overlap. For that you'll need to know exactly the size of the label in plot units (and this requires quite the bit of code).

Comment: You are using "U10" as dtype. I am having very long entries for names. What is the best dtype to use for strings with variable length?

Comment: I am using 'U32' and for long strings i get this error:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: @gustavz One way to test it is just to build a numpy array with the biggest string you might have and what its `dtype` is, like this `a = np.array(["reallyreallylongstring])` and then `print(a.dtype)`. But your problem seems to be related with some character that does not have a rule for utf-8. Try removing all characters with accentuation (German umlauts perhpaps?) or that might seem non standard. There should be ways to use those characters but first you need to check if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: I solved it switching from numpy matrix to initializing a 2d list mat=[['','','']['','','']['','','']]. This is not winning a beauty award, but it works.